# Image from CIFilter wont display

Tags: swift, cifilter, ciimage

I'm taking a snapshot of a subview and turning it into an image:

```
let image = UIImage(view: swiftyDraw)
let scaledImage = scaleImage(image: image, toSize: CGSize(width: 28, height:28))
```

finalImage is a `UIImageView` and setting it to display the scaledImage works, I can see it fine:

```
finalImage.image = scaledImage //this works
```

However, I want to invert the colors before displaying it:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")
filter!.setValue(CIImage(image: scaledImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let invertedImage = UIImage(ciImage: filter!.outputImage!)
finalImage.image = invertedImage //this does not work
```

Nothing shows up when I set finalImage.image to invertedImage, but it shows up fine when it's set to scaledImage.

Edit: scaleImage function:

```
func scaleImage (image: UIImage, toSize size:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your "scaledImage" is an `UIImage`, so you can directly get an `CIImage` without creating a new one.

```
guard let ciImage = scaledImage.ciImage, let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert") else {
    fatalError("CIImage conversion fail")
}
//Now access the CIFilter object to filter the image
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
finalImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!)
```

> Update

In case, if you are `fatalError` means `UIImage` doesn't exists with `CIImage` so you need to convert `UIImage` to `CIImage`.

```
extension UIImage {
    var toCIImage: CIImage {
        return self.CIImage ?? CIImage(CGImage: self.CGImage!)
    }
}

guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert") else {
    fatalError("CIImage conversion fail")
}

let ciImage = scaledImage.toCIImage
//Now access the CIFilter object to filter the image
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
finalImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: filter.outputImage!)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting Thread 1: Fatal error: CIImage conversion fail

I updated the question with the contents of scaleImage, which should be returning a UIImage

Comment: Thanks, its working, I also found out that the background isn't included, so it's inverting my black stoke to white and displaying on a white background.  So even though your code worked, it was invisible until I changed colors.  Thank you for your help!